# How to use arrays in lambda expressions?

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I am writing a program with NEST library of ElasticSearch. I want to write a lambda expression for a function with this argument:

```
HighlighDescriptor<parentdocument> HighlighDescriptor.onFields
    (param Action<HighlightFieldDescriptor<ParentDocument>>[] fieldHighlighters)
```

I don't know what is the array in the function argument?

Comment: Could you explain more what do you want?

Read here http://www.dotnetperls.com/lambda, it could be beneficial

Comment: i want to write the argument of onFields method, but i cant.

Comment: Be more specific, its not very clear what you want to do

Comment: @user2352554 do you want to write it as lambda expression

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`params`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w5zay9db.aspx) keyword in C# indicates that the method takes a variable number of parameters. For example, a method with this signature:

```
public void DoStuff(params string[] values) { ... }
```

Could be called like this:

```
DoStuff();
DoStuff("value1");
DoStuff("value1", "value2", "value3", "value4", "value5");
//etc.
```

So in your case, the array is for you to specify any number of `Action` values. An example would be:

```
blah.OnFields(
    f => f.OnField("field1").PreTags("<span>").PostTags("</span>"),
    f => f.OnField("field2").PreTags("<span>").PostTags("</span>"),
    f => f.OnField("field3").PreTags("<span>").PostTags("</span>")
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's take a look at the parameter's type:

```
params Action<highlightfielddescriptor<parentdocument>> []
```

Note the `params` keyword, this tells the compiler that the associated method can take a **variable** number of arguments. This means that you are able to pass in multiple `Action<highlightfielddescriptor<parentdocument>>` objects.

According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/018hxwa8%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> [...] The Action Delegate encapsulates a method that has a single parameter and does not return a value

In an `Action`, this "*single parameter*" is of the type of the Action's generic type argument. In your case, this single parameter will be of type `<highlightfielddescriptor<parentdocument>>`

In C#, you express lambda expressions with the following syntax:

```
(parameters) => (body)
```

With this in mind, an `Action<highlightfielddescriptor<parentdocument>>` can be translated to something like this:

```
Action<highlightfielddescriptor<parentdocument>> action = (fieldDescriptor) => {
   //... Your code here
};
```

`fieldDescriptor` is a local variable (of type `highlightfielddescriptor<parentdocument>`), which will hold an instance delegated to you by the `onFields` method

Now you can call the method like this:

```
var descriptor = HighlighDescriptor.onFields((fieldDescriptor) => {
      //Your code here...
});
```

Or even like this:

```
var descriptor = HighlighDescriptor.onFields((f) => {
       //Do something
}, (f) => {
       //Do something else
}, (f) => {
       //An action can also have an empty body
});
```

Notice the multiple actions.

**PS**: Remember that `Action` delegates cannot return a value!

This expression is an invalid `Action` delegate:

```
(value) => {
    DoSomething(value);
    return value; //WRONG!
}
```